# Toggle system dark mode from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, dark-mode

How can I toggle the system dark mode from Terminal without using AppleScript? I have already searched things like "zsh toggle dark mode" and "terminal set dark mode mac", but I can't find relevant results. Is there any way to do this? I'd like to do it without AppleScript unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do this without AppleScript, but you can do it in one line using it:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to tell appearance preferences to set dark mode to not dark mode'
```

From https://brettterpstra.com/2018/09/26/shell-tricks-toggling-dark-mode-from-terminal/

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure all documents in other apps are saved and that other apps are closed, because you should restart your Mac at the end of this.**

1. Open Terminal.
2. Run `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist _HIEnableThemeSwitchHotKey -bool true`

   (you can copy/paste this into your Terminal command line if you prefer).
3. Because you're entering a `sudo` command, macOS will prompt you to enter your administrator password.. Enter it and hit return.
4. Quit the Terminal app.
5. Restart your Mac.

Comment: it's fine to quote the relevant part from [a different source](https://www.imore.com/how-enable-os-xs-dark-mode-key-command), but then at least include that you've done so with a link to [where you found it](https://www.imore.com/how-enable-os-xs-dark-mode-key-command#:~:text=Make%20sure%20all,Restart%20your%20Mac.)